# Not rendering Chinese characters on in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding, properties

I am trying to display chines characters but its showing ??????????. In my spring-servlet I have

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

and in my massages.property I have added some chines characters like this 
    這對中國的考驗

First line of my .jsp file I have

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

If I encode the chines in ascii format then its working fine. but I don't want to do that. Is there anything I am missing.

Please help.

Comment: Is the encoding of massages.property also UTF8? I don't know if it matters, might be worth a shot.

Comment: yes I have saved it as UTF8 using notepad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [their documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), the properties files are by default read using ISO-8859-1 encoding. You'd need to use unicode escapes like as in `\uXXXX` for each character beyond [the supported range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) of ISO-8859-1. JDK offers the `native2ascii` tool for this in the `/bin` folder. You should then use the converted properties file instead.

E.g. (in command console)

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 some.properties.utf8 some.properties
```

Where `some.properties.utf8` is the properties file which you saved in UTF-8 and `some.properties` is the converted properties file which you should instead use in your web application.

The

```
some.key = 這對中國的考驗
```

would then become

```
some.key = \u9019\u5c0d\u4e2d\u570b\u7684\u8003\u9a57
```

Most IDEs like Eclipse, IntelliJ and maybe also Netbeans (not sure as I've never used it) will automatically do this when you use the builtin properties file editor.

Comment: Hi BalusC, If I convert my code to some.key = \u9019\u5c0d\u4e2d\u570b\u7684\u8003\u9a57 this then it works fine.So , is it mandatory that I have to encode my .property file to UTF-8 as you mentioned

Comment: No. They are by default read using ISO-8859-1. Any character which is not supported by ISO-8859-1 needs to be escaped by `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is the unicode hex representation of the character. This way you can save it as ISO-8859-1, so that they can be read properly. If the properties files were by default read using UTF-8, that would not have been necessary, but this is thus not the case. See also the links in my answer and [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).

Comment: Thanks Balus for nice explaination

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the encoding to UTF-16
{In property file and in spring bean file}

Some extra words :
Chinese characters occupy two bytes so actually it should be strange how they can be represented in UTF-8 format (which ideally should read 8 bits at a time-- my assumption)
Anyways the fact is we can represent chinese character can be represented in UTF-8 format some how.