# Unable to login with Chinese username spring Mvc

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, utf-8

I configured spring Mvc application with basic spring security against MySQL. To support internationalisation I Defined `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter` with UTF-8 in `web.xml`, specified UTF-8 in tomcat `server.xml` and modified MySQL table to support UTF-8 encoding.

Login page has `contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"`.
I am able to create Chinese username and save in MySQL. When trying to login with Chinese username the user name in spring authentication provider is not UTF-8 and so fetch username fails.

How could we fix this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559447/not-rendering-chinese-characters-on-in-spring-mvc?rq=1

Comment: Resource bundle is picked up properly. I am able to show Chinese characters on screen. Only problem is, I can't login with a Chinese username